# Fetching data asynchronously in VueJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I want to display data fetched from the following function:

```
 async getData() {
      let skus = this.skusData;
      const app = { $axios: this.$axios };
      let skusId = this.idSkus;
      const skusPrices = await endPoint.getPrices(app, skusId);
      let data = skus.map((item, i) =>
        Object.assign({}, item, skusPrices[i])
      );
      return data;
    }
async mounted() {
    await this.getData();
  },
```

And I would like to display as such:

```
<div v-for="item in this.getData" :key="item.id">
      <my-favourite
        :name="item.name"
        :img-favorite="item.pictures"
        :color="item.color"
        :price="item.inclTax"
      />
    </div>
```

However, it is not working as intended.

Comment: thanks @pawel to edit my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many issues with your code (logically and syntactically). I would structure as follows:

```
data() {
  return {
    skuData: []
  }
},
 async getData() {
    const { data } = await this.$axios.get('endpoint');
    this.skuData = data // or however it is sent back
 },
 mounted() {
   this.getData();
  },
```

And then in your template:

Do not use `this` in your template (it isn't available there).

```
<div v-for="item in skuData" :key="item.id">
      <my-favourite
        :name="item.name"
        :img-favorite="item.pictures"
        :color="item.color"
        :price="item.inclTax"
      />
</div>
```

Let me know where you get with the above and we can move stuff around accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I resolve my question @riza khan is good but your function don't return and async mounted

```
data() {
  return {
    skuData: []
  }
},
 async getData() {
    const  data  = await this.$axios.get('endpoint');
    return this.skuData.push(data) // or however it is sent back;
    
 },
 async mounted() {
   await this.getData();
  },
```

Comment: Neither of those are necessary; you aren't using the return value of `getData()`, and since there's no logic in `mounted()` aside from calling `getData()`, there's no need for it to be async either.